# Many to many relation in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I have two models in my nosql database(mongoDB and mongoose.js): *User* and *Class*.

Each class has one teacher and many students (teacher and students are *User* model).

and each user could have many classes.

What is the best solution for implementing database?

I think having array of `user_id` inside *Class* model and array of `class_id` in *User* model is best, am I right?

assume teacher user can not be as student and student user can not be as teacher, too.

Comment: @AndrewLi This is only many to many relation in my db, and I have to use nosql.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mongoose's `ref` (see the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-ref)) in your schemas. E.g:

```
const UserSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    // other properties you want to define
    classes: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Class"
        }
    ]
})

const ClassSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    className: String,
    // other properties you want to define
    users: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }
    ]
})
```

Later when querying the DB you can use mongoose's [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents) to automatically get the referenced documents, instead of just the document's id:

```
User.findById(userId).populate("classes");
Class.findById(classId).populate("users");
```

Here's a nice tutorial, that explains it in further detail:
https://bezkoder.com/mongodb-many-to-many-mongoose/

Comment: This is not answer for my question. I know how to implement this. I what to know is this solution best for this db?

Comment: Afaik that's the way to go if you need to do this in mongodb. Read the section "References or Embedding for MongoDB Many-to-Many Relationships" in the linked article - it explains it quite well in my opinion :)